# Android SurfaceView not showing onDraw

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

For simpleness of the question, I'm drawing an integer on a SurfaceView which increases by 1 every draw.
The increasing actually happens, as I can see on the System.out.
The text on the screen stays on '0'.
Who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

SurfaceViewTest.java

```
package com.niek.surfaceviewtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SurfaceViewTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

StatusView.java

```
package com.niek.surfaceviewtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class StatusView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private int tmp;
    private DrawThread drawThread;

    public StatusView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawText(tmp + "", 10, 10, p);
        tmp++;

        System.out.println(tmp);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        drawThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

    protected class DrawThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private boolean isRunning;

        public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            isRunning = false;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            isRunning = run;
        }

        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (isRunning) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        onDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <com.niek.surfaceviewtest.StatusView
        android:id="@+id/statusview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="#000000"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [thread-necro] This doesn't work because it's mixing up the Surface and View parts of the SurfaceView.  `onDraw()` is used to draw on the View part, but for a SurfaceView the View should be a transparent hole (needed by the layout code) that lets you see through to the independent Surface layer behind. The first call to `onDraw()` clears the View to *opaque* black, so nothing rendered on the Surface is ever visible. The implementation above, combined with the accepted answer below, results in a custom View with unnecessary overhead. Specifying a background for the View is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My only guess is that painting isn't being done on the surface because the view isn't invalidated. You're supposed to call [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) in order to draw, and then let the framework call `onDraw()`. Maybe that's why `tmp` is being incremented, but the paint operation only reaches the surface the first time.

It might be worth experimenting: maybe make `Canvas c` a member of `StatusView`, and then replace

```
synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
  onDraw(c);
}
```

with

```
synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
  invalidate();
}
```

Does that work?

Comment: That actually did work. But instead of invalidate() I had to call postInvalidate() to or a CalledFromWrongThreadException was thrown.
Still finding it weird, as I basically copy-pasted 90% of it from [here](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html)

Comment: Oh, of course. It actually says so in the documentation I linked to! "This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate()." Glad it worked.

Comment: Does the 'invalidate' call really need synchronizing? Isn't it just telling the surface to draw it from its own thread?

Comment: @noelicus Yeah, I think you're right. Since the actual call is `postInvalidate()`, all interaction with the `SurfaceHolder` will take place on the UI thread. Does `DrawThread` even need a reference to `SurfaceHolder` at all? Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

The current solution is not right. You are using the `SurfaceView` in order to update the content from a separate thread and not using the `invalidate()` method that will run `onDraw()` method when the system refreshes the content. The problem is that you have set a background for your `StatusView`, try deleting that line

```
android:background="#000000"
```

apparently, you need to control the whole information displayed in that view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are showing your main.xml with setContentView(R.layout.main); instead of creating the surface and displaying that.  unless i am missing code somewhere I don't see that as being the case.

Comment: `R.layout.main` refers to the XML file (main.xml) that specifies `com.niek.surfaceviewtest.StatusView`. I think it should work.

Comment: whoops my bad.. looks like you are calling it in the main.xml I am new to this too and didn't know you could do that through the xml.  lol